# Validación en un array en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo estos valores del array y el metodo `getRowsNum` me devuelve el número de filas que tengo en un grid, pero al momento de igualar el array `itemsArray` que contiene todos las filas de los grid con el valor "igual" no me despliega ninguna información, solo quiero que los valores de mi array que no tienen filas se muestre.

Este es el código:

```
function verificaGrid(callback) {
    var vacios = "";
    var igual = 0;
    var itemsArray = new Array(6);
    itemsArray[0] = hermanosGrid.getRowsNum();
    itemsArray[1] = gradosGrid.getRowsNum();
    itemsArray[2] = viajesGrid1.getRowsNum();
    itemsArray[3] = viajesGrid2.getRowsNum();
    itemsArray[4] = guarderiaGrid.getRowsNum();
    itemsArray[5] = estimulacionGrid.getRowsNum();


    formFormularios.forEachItem(function(i) {

        for (var i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
            if (itemsArray[i] == igual) {
                dhtmlx.alert(loader.xmlDoc.responseText);
                itemsArray.splice(i);
                vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(i) + "|";
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    vacios = vacios.substr(0, (vacios.length - 1));

    if (itemsArray.length > 0) {
        showEmptyFields(vacios, itemsArray.length);
    } else {
        if (callback && typeof(callback) == "function") {
            callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías incluir la definición o una referencia a `forEachItem`. Por otro lado, no me queda claro que recorrer con el `forEachItem` junto con el `for`. Finalmente, `i` lo pasas como parámetro de la función y luego lo redefines (?) en el `for`, yo le pondría otro nombre a uno de los dos, el parámetro de la función o la variable del `for` (ej: `j`).

Answer (score 3):

Quite `return false;` y ya no detiene el `for`.